# How to vectorize a function that depends on a previous calculation in R?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have a random walk with some drift. My goal is to create a function that adds a column to this `data.table` labeling the "zone" its in based on its cumulative % gain and % drawdown.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
# generate random returns with drift
df <- data.table(
    "date" = 1:50,
    "ret" = rnorm(50, mean = .002, sd = .01)
)
# calculate the value of the random-walk over-time
df[, val := cumprod(1 + ret)]
df[, draw_down := val / cummax(val) - 1]
```

The first zone occurs in the first row and goes up until either a `5% cumulative gain` or `2% drawdown` occurs.

The second zone starts one row after the first zone ends, and continues until the same happens again, a `5% cumulative gain` or `2% drawdown`

This repeats until neither of those things occur, in which case the zone continues to the last row.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# start with the first row and zone of 1
idx <- 1
count <- 1
res <- data.table()
while (idx <= nrow(df)) {

    # grab the start of the zone and all future rows
    tmp <- df[idx:.N]
    # calculate the necessary things
    tmp[, val := cumprod(1 + ret)]
    tmp[, draw_down := val / cummax(val) - 1]

    # find out if we crossed our drawdown threshold
    loss_idx <- which(
        tmp$draw_down == min(tmp$draw_down[tmp$draw_down <= -.02])
    )
    # find out if we crossed gain threshold
    gain_idx <- which(tmp$val == min(tmp$val[tmp$val >= 1.05]))
    # if we have no thresholds, label the rest of the zones
    # and exit
    if (length(loss_idx) == 0 & length(gain_idx) == 0) {
        tmp[, zone := count]
        res <- rbind(res, tmp)
        break
    }
    # mark the zone
    tmp[1:min(gain_idx, loss_idx), zone := count]
    # increment our index
    idx <- tmp[min(gain_idx, loss_idx)]$date + 1
    print(idx)
    # increment our zone
    count <- count + 1
    res <- rbind(res, tmp[!is.na(zone)])
}
```

I have tried getting the indices of where these zone points would occur. But then I run into the problem of needing to recalculate the `val` and `drawdown` based on the last zone's index. I cannot figure out a way to vectorize that. Maybe using a `roll` function would be effective here?

The problem boils down to knowing the draw-down by zone, but needing the previous zone in order to calculate the draw-down. Similarly with the cumulative return. Is it possible to vectorize this function if it depends on the previous value?

Any help in any direction would be greatly appreciated in trying to achieved the desired output below.

the desired output:

```
> res
date    ret val draw_down   zone
<int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   -0.0042645381   0.9957355   0.0000000000    1
2   0.0038364332    0.9995555   0.0000000000    1
3   -0.0063562861   0.9932021   -0.0063562861   1
4   0.0179528080    1.0110328   0.0000000000    1
5   0.0052950777    1.0163863   0.0000000000    1
6   -0.0062046838   1.0100800   -0.0062046838   1
7   0.0068742905    1.0170236   0.0000000000    1
8   0.0093832471    1.0265665   0.0000000000    1
9   0.0077578135    1.0345305   0.0000000000    1
10  -0.0010538839   1.0334402   -0.0010538839   1
11  0.0171178117    1.0511304   0.0000000000    1
12  0.0058984324    1.0058984   0.0000000000    2
13  -0.0042124058   1.0016612   -0.0042124058   2
14  -0.0201469989   0.9814807   -0.0242745373   2
15  0.0132493092    1.0132493   0.0000000000    3
16  0.0015506639    1.0148205   0.0000000000    3
17  0.0018380974    1.0166859   0.0000000000    3
18  0.0114383621    1.0283151   0.0000000000    3
19  0.0102122120    1.0388164   0.0000000000    3
20  0.0079390132    1.0470636   0.0000000000    3
21  0.0111897737    1.0587800   0.0000000000    3
22  0.0098213630    1.0691787   0.0000000000    3
23  0.0027456498    1.0721143   0.0000000000    3
24  -0.0178935170   1.0529304   -0.0178935170   3
25  0.0081982575    1.0615626   -0.0098419551   3
26  0.0014387126    1.0630899   -0.0084174023   3
27  0.0004420449    1.0635598   -0.0079790782   3
28  -0.0127075238   1.0500446   -0.0205852077   3
29  -0.0027815006   0.9972185   0.0000000000    4
30  0.0061794156    1.0033807   0.0000000000    4
31  0.0155867955    1.0190202   0.0000000000    4
32  0.0009721227    1.0200108   0.0000000000    4
33  0.0058767161    1.0260051   0.0000000000    4
34  0.0014619496    1.0275051   0.0000000000    4
35  -0.0117705956   1.0154108   -0.0117705956   4
36  -0.0021499456   1.0132277   -0.0138952351   4
37  -0.0019428995   1.0112591   -0.0158111376   4
38  0.0014068660    1.0126818   -0.0144265157   4
39  0.0130002537    1.0258469   -0.0016138103   4
40  0.0096317575    1.0357276   0.0000000000    4
41  0.0003547640    1.0360951   0.0000000000    4
42  -0.0005336168   1.0355422   -0.0005336168   4
43  0.0089696338    1.0448306   0.0000000000    4
44  0.0075666320    1.0527365   0.0000000000    4
45  -0.0048875569   0.9951124   0.0000000000    5
46  -0.0050749516   0.9900623   -0.0050749516   5
47  0.0056458196    0.9956520   0.0000000000    5
48  0.0096853292    1.0052952   0.0000000000    5
49  0.0008765379    1.0061764   0.0000000000    5
50  0.0108110773    1.0170543   0.0000000000    5
```

Comment: One doubt: How are you planning to calculate the ```2% drawdown``` when the ```draw_down=0```? Because there is no threshold for that, as 0*0.98 is 0. And so, the 4th row will have zone 2.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. The 2% drawdown is really a -2% threshold. So a drawdown of 0 doesn’t trigger anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are exploring vectorization to speed up the calculations, here is another option to speed up the calculations using `Rccp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("IntegerVector zoning(NumericVector idx) {
    int zone = 1, n = idx.size();
    IntegerVector res = IntegerVector(n);
    double x0 = idx[0];


    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = zone;
        if (idx[i]/x0 < 0.98 || idx[i]/x0 > 1.05) {
            if (i+1 < n) {
                x0 = idx[i+1];
            }
            zone++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}")

df[, zone := zoning(c(1, val))[-1L]]
```

output:

```
    date           ret       val zone
 1:    1 -0.0042645381 0.9957355    1
 2:    2  0.0038364332 0.9995555    1
 3:    3 -0.0063562861 0.9932021    1
 4:    4  0.0179528080 1.0110328    1
 5:    5  0.0052950777 1.0163863    1
 6:    6 -0.0062046838 1.0100800    1
 7:    7  0.0068742905 1.0170236    1
 8:    8  0.0093832471 1.0265665    1
 9:    9  0.0077578135 1.0345305    1
10:   10 -0.0010538839 1.0334402    1
11:   11  0.0171178117 1.0511304    1
12:   12  0.0058984324 1.0573304    2
13:   13 -0.0042124058 1.0528765    2
14:   14 -0.0201469989 1.0316642    2
15:   15  0.0132493092 1.0453331    3
16:   16  0.0015506639 1.0469540    3
17:   17  0.0018380974 1.0488784    3
18:   18  0.0114383621 1.0608759    3
19:   19  0.0102122120 1.0717098    3
20:   20  0.0079390132 1.0802181    3
21:   21  0.0111897737 1.0923055    3
22:   22  0.0098213630 1.1030334    3
23:   23  0.0027456498 1.1060620    4
24:   24 -0.0178935170 1.0862706    4
25:   25  0.0081982575 1.0951762    4
26:   26  0.0014387126 1.0967518    4
27:   27  0.0004420449 1.0972366    4
28:   28 -0.0127075238 1.0832934    4
29:   29 -0.0027815006 1.0802803    5
30:   30  0.0061794156 1.0869558    5
31:   31  0.0155867955 1.1038979    5
32:   32  0.0009721227 1.1049710    5
33:   33  0.0058767161 1.1114646    5
34:   34  0.0014619496 1.1130896    5
35:   35 -0.0117705956 1.0999878    5
36:   36 -0.0021499456 1.0976229    5
37:   37 -0.0019428995 1.0954903    5
38:   38  0.0014068660 1.0970316    5
39:   39  0.0130002537 1.1112932    5
40:   40  0.0096317575 1.1219969    5
41:   41  0.0003547640 1.1223950    5
42:   42 -0.0005336168 1.1217961    5
43:   43  0.0089696338 1.1318582    5
44:   44  0.0075666320 1.1404225    5
45:   45 -0.0048875569 1.1348486    6
46:   46 -0.0050749516 1.1290893    6
47:   47  0.0056458196 1.1354640    6
48:   48  0.0096853292 1.1464613    6
49:   49  0.0008765379 1.1474662    6
50:   50  0.0108110773 1.1598716    6
    date           ret       val zone
```

Courtesy of https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: yeah this is incredibly fast! just ran the benchmark compared to @r2evans. ~5000x. faster
1ms vs 5000ms for 100,000 rows

Comment: the reason for vectorization is speed, but my C++ is very weak. Eventually this function will be somewhat more complicated, so I was hoping to be able to do most of it in R. but this might just mean i'll have to strengthen my C++ skills. going to try a few more vectorization methods before accepting this as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a rolling calculation is the right way to go: typically they have fixed windows, whereas this is a bit more dynamic. Similarly, a cumulative operation (e.g., `cumsum`) won't work for similar reasons. (That's not to say that I can't warp a `zoo::rollapply` approach to do this, but I think it'd be much less efficient than this recommended approach.)

Here's a simple `while` loop that appears to provide the `zone` you're asking for:

```r
breaks <- integer(0)
rn <- 1L
while (rn <= nrow(df)) {
  theserows <- seq(rn, nrow(df))
  ratios <- df$val[theserows] / df$val[theserows][1]
  upordown <- which(ratios >= 1.05 | ratios <= 0.98)
  if (!length(upordown)) break
  breaks <- c(breaks, upordown[1] + rn)
  rn <- rn + upordown[1]
}
df[, zone := cumsum(seq_len(.N) %in% breaks)]
#      date           ret       val     draw_down  zone
#     <int>         <num>     <num>         <num> <int>
#  1:     1 -0.0042645381 0.9957355  0.0000000000     0
#  2:     2  0.0038364332 0.9995555  0.0000000000     0
#  3:     3 -0.0063562861 0.9932021 -0.0063562861     0
#  4:     4  0.0179528080 1.0110328  0.0000000000     0
#  5:     5  0.0052950777 1.0163863  0.0000000000     0
#  6:     6 -0.0062046838 1.0100800 -0.0062046838     0
#  7:     7  0.0068742905 1.0170236  0.0000000000     0
#  8:     8  0.0093832471 1.0265665  0.0000000000     0
#  9:     9  0.0077578135 1.0345305  0.0000000000     0
# 10:    10 -0.0010538839 1.0334402 -0.0010538839     0
# 11:    11  0.0171178117 1.0511304  0.0000000000     0
# 12:    12  0.0058984324 1.0573304  0.0000000000     1
# 13:    13 -0.0042124058 1.0528765 -0.0042124058     1
# 14:    14 -0.0201469989 1.0316642 -0.0242745373     1
# 15:    15  0.0132493092 1.0453331 -0.0113468490     2
# 16:    16  0.0015506639 1.0469540 -0.0098137803     2
# 17:    17  0.0018380974 1.0488784 -0.0079937216     2
# 18:    18  0.0114383621 1.0608759  0.0000000000     2
# 19:    19  0.0102122120 1.0717098  0.0000000000     2
# 20:    20  0.0079390132 1.0802181  0.0000000000     2
# 21:    21  0.0111897737 1.0923055  0.0000000000     2
# 22:    22  0.0098213630 1.1030334  0.0000000000     2
# 23:    23  0.0027456498 1.1060620  0.0000000000     3
# 24:    24 -0.0178935170 1.0862706 -0.0178935170     3
# 25:    25  0.0081982575 1.0951762 -0.0098419551     3
# 26:    26  0.0014387126 1.0967518 -0.0084174023     3
# 27:    27  0.0004420449 1.0972366 -0.0079790782     3
# 28:    28 -0.0127075238 1.0832934 -0.0205852077     3
# 29:    29 -0.0027815006 1.0802803 -0.0233094505     4
# 30:    30  0.0061794156 1.0869558 -0.0172740737     4
# 31:    31  0.0155867955 1.1038979 -0.0019565256     4
# 32:    32  0.0009721227 1.1049710 -0.0009863049     4
# 33:    33  0.0058767161 1.1114646  0.0000000000     4
# 34:    34  0.0014619496 1.1130896  0.0000000000     4
# 35:    35 -0.0117705956 1.0999878 -0.0117705956     4
# 36:    36 -0.0021499456 1.0976229 -0.0138952351     4
# 37:    37 -0.0019428995 1.0954903 -0.0158111376     4
# 38:    38  0.0014068660 1.0970316 -0.0144265157     4
# 39:    39  0.0130002537 1.1112932 -0.0016138103     4
# 40:    40  0.0096317575 1.1219969  0.0000000000     4
# 41:    41  0.0003547640 1.1223950  0.0000000000     4
# 42:    42 -0.0005336168 1.1217961 -0.0005336168     4
# 43:    43  0.0089696338 1.1318582  0.0000000000     4
# 44:    44  0.0075666320 1.1404225  0.0000000000     4
# 45:    45 -0.0048875569 1.1348486 -0.0048875569     5
# 46:    46 -0.0050749516 1.1290893 -0.0099377044     5
# 47:    47  0.0056458196 1.1354640 -0.0043479913     5
# 48:    48  0.0096853292 1.1464613  0.0000000000     5
# 49:    49  0.0008765379 1.1474662  0.0000000000     5
# 50:    50  0.0108110773 1.1598716  0.0000000000     5
#      date           ret       val     draw_down  zone
```

And a simple function to do the same:

```r
func <- function(x, up = 1.05, down = 0.98) {
  breaks <- integer(0)
  if (!length(x)) return(breaks)
  ind <- 1L
  while (ind <= length(x)) {
    theseind <- seq(ind, length(x))
    ratios <- x[theseind] / x[theseind][1]
    upordown <- which(ratios >= up | ratios <= down)
    if (!length(upordown)) break
    breaks <- c(breaks, upordown[1] + ind)
    ind <- ind + upordown[1]
  }
  return(cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% breaks))
}
df[, zone := func(val, 1.05, 0.98) ]
```

Comment: i will run a benchmark once I get back to my machine. I've looked into `frollapply` but as you said the window is pre-known, or pre-computable to use those types of functions. Would doing something recursively work faster? Maybe with `findInterval`? I'm going to try some things

Comment: I could not think of a vectorizable or rollable solution that seemed anywhere near as efficient as this. The loop repeats (in this case) 5 times, whereas `frollapply` and other rolling-function facilitators tend to run `nrow(df)` times, give or take, which is not better. R doesn't do tail-recursion very well (if I could craft a tail-recursion approach to this ... haven't tried), so its recursion efficiency is a little lower here. I'll be interested to know if you find something else that is faster.

Comment: yeah this is very efficient and way better than what i currently have. not even worth running the benchmark. struggling to find a vectorized solution. will keep trying for now
`Rcpp` might also be another option I might have to use. This will eventually be run on millions of rows

Comment: data.table rolling functions don't have fixed windows if you use adaptive=TRUE

Comment: @jangorecki, the issue (as I see it) with an adaptive window is that in this problem, we don't know a priori what the widths are; in fact, the basis of my `while` loop are to be able to determine the changeover-indices, at which point we no longer need `frollapply`. I'd really appreciate seeing if that can be done easily. Thanks for piping in!

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't looked into problem actually, it sounds that could be done in two passes. First compute window width, and then use adaptive roll. Again, sorry if it doesn't fit to this problem and only confuses.

Comment: I think the first pass in your two-pass suggestion is actually the work that needs to be done ... the request was how to determine the groups, not how to do something with those groups. No worries about not looking deeply, it's a reminder to look at not-yet-learned arguments/functions. Thanks!

Comment: the goal is eventually do something with these groups. I imagined using `data.table`'s `by` to do this. I think that would be the most efficient way?

Comment: It is, but (as always) it may depend on what you're hoping to do. I think the answers here address *this question*, and "doing something" with each group is a very different question from "how to define the groups". With that, if you're satisfied with one of the answers, I suggest you accept one and consider a new question focused on what you need done to each group.